# How many people required to complete a job?

Tags: percentages

I am facing issue solving below problem. Any help?

Total number of tasks are 6780 in a year. And 17 people are efficiently working in a year to complete different tasks to 100%.

Now there will be 20% work increase next year.

How many more people we require to handle that 20% extra load efficiently?

Comment: Update the question... is that now make sense?

Comment: Yes, see the answer below. Is that what you were looking for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality assume that the workload of the current year corresponds to 100 units (of tasks if you will). Each person can therefore handle $100/17$ units of workload. Next year there will be 120 units, and we know that $x$ people can handle $x\times(100/17)$ units. Thus the solution to how many people we need (in total) for next years 120 units of workload is the solution of: $x\times(100/17)=120$, with respect to $x$.

Comment: This make sense to me... I have updated the question as I am able to fetch number of tasks from cms... +1

Comment: This seems unnecessarily complicated for what is basically a percentage increase question.

Answer (score 3):

Work and manpower are in direct proportion (at least this is the ideal case for your problem). So if you have a 20% increase in the work, then you should have a 20%=3.4 people increase in the manpower too in order to complete the work in the same time. This is regardless of the number of tasks.